# What site search solution to choose for an e-commerce website?

Tags: e-commerce

I am researching whether Google Site Search (free or paid does not matter) is relevant for an e-commerce website. I cannot find much examples of e-commerce websites using it or integrations of the Google Site Search in different e-commerce system like Magento, Shopify, etc.
Do you think the Google Site Search with its API and everything could make a good search for an e-commerce website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can consider eCommerce SAAS options such as Nextopia, Easyask, Inferlytics, SearchSpring  or go for an opensource such as SOLR or elastic search.